# Abstract Rewriting Challenge (Robbers)

Tags: cops-and-robbers, repeated-transformation, grammars

This is a somewhat [proof-golf](/questions/tagged/proof-golf)-like [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge. This is the robbers' thread; [the cops' thread is here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157094/abstract-rewriting-challenge-cops).

## Robbers

The cops will post abstract rewriting systems. Your task is to crack their submissions by proving that the target string either can or can not be reached from the source string by applying their rewrite rules. (You can do this either by posting a sequence of rewrite rules that starts with the source string and ends with the target, or by proving mathematically that this does, or does not, exist.)

See the [cops' thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157094/abstract-rewriting-challenge-cops) for details and definitions.

Comment: Do'h! I put a bounty on the wrong question, this was meant to be on the cops' challenge. So somebody will get a random bounty.

Comment: No worries, I have refunded the bounty.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem: Huh... so that's why the [SE API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/featured-questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=codegolf&run=true) is listing this question as featured, but with no bounty amount or closing date. :o Oh well, time to add some input validation to my user script.

Answer (score 17):

## [jimmy23013](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157133/68942)

Let's work backwards for this one. We first turn the digits into their binary representations. We go from `VW626206555675126212043640270477001760465526277571600601` to `VW++__+_++__+____++_+_++_++_+++_++++_+__+_+_++__+___+_+____+___++++_+______+_+++___+__++++++________++++++____+__++_+_++_+_+_++__+_+++++++_++++__+++_______++______+`. Next, we keep applying the inverse of `DCW:W+` and `DW:W_` until we clear all symbols. Our result is now `VDCDCDDDCDDCDCDDDCDDDDDCDCDDCDDCDCDDCDCDDCDCDCDDCDCDCDCDDCDDDCDDCDDCDCDDDCDDDDCDDCDDDDDCDDDDCDCDCDCDDCDDDDDDDCDDCDCDCDDDDCDDDCDCDCDCDCDCDDDDDDDDDCDCDCDCDCDCDDDDDCDDDCDCDDCDDCDCDDCDDCDDCDCDDDCDDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDDCDCDCDCDDDCDCDCDDDDDDDDCDCDDDDDDDCW`. We now want to make this string match `VD+C+W`; that is, we want to move all of the `D`s to the left of all of the `C`s. This can be done by reversing `DCC:CD`. We do this by repeating the following algorithm:

1. Find the first `D` that is to the right of a block of `C`s.
2. Move the `D` to the left of that block.
3. Double the number of `C`s.

Through some math, we can determine that we will end up with 123 `D`s and 4638704741628490670592103344196019722536654143873 `C`s (you were right about this not fitting in an SE answer... I doubt this would fit if stored as states of all of the atoms in the Earth combined :P).

If we keep applying the reverse of `V:VD`, we can get rid of all of the `D`s now, so we get `VCCC.......CCCW`. We convert the `V` back into `YZ`. Now we have `YZCCC.......CCCW`.

We want to be able to get rid of all of the `C`s and have it in the form `YAAA...AAABBB...BBBZW`. Fortunately, this can be done by the following method. Firstly, we inverse-apply `YB:Y` 587912508217580921743211 times to get `YBBB.......BBBZCCC.......CCCW`. Then, we repeat the following sequence of steps (where `[?*]` means any number of `?`, not necessarily greater than zero):

1. Inverse-apply `CZ:ZC` 587912508217580921743211 times to get `Y[A*]BBB.......BBBCCC.......CCCZCCC.......CCCW`
2. Inverse-apply `CB:BC` many times to get `Y[A*]BCBCBC.......BCBCBCZCCC.......CCCW`
3. Inverse-apply `AZ:Z` and `AB:BCA` many times to get `Y[A*]ABBB.......BBBZCCC.......CCCW`

Through induction, we see that we can move the `BZ` combination all the way to the end (except before the `W`) and then the number of `A`s is 1/587912508217580921743211 of the number of `C`s, leaving us with 7890127658096618386747843 `A`s. We now have `YAAA.......AAABBB.......BBBZW`. Convert the `ZW` back to a `U`, then inverse-apply `U:BU` many times to keep only 2 `B`s and then convert the `BBU` to a `T`, and you now have `YAAA.......AAAT`. Then, you can inverse-apply `T:AAAAAT` many times to get `YAAAT` because the number of `A`s was 3 larger than a multiple of 5.

Thanks for the challenge!

Comment: Is it stated anywhere or is it by default that inverse apply is allowed?

Comment: @WeijunZhou I mean, if applying `A:B` to `ABC` gives `BBC`, it's obvious that applying the inverse of `A:B` to `BBC` can give `ABC`. It's not specifically stated that it's allowed, but I can easily just reverse my steps and have a "conventional" solution, it's just that it's easier to go backwards IMO.

Comment: I mean ,for example, if there is only one rule `A:B` and it is not stated that inverse apply is allowed then I don't think you can go from `BBC` to `ABC`. This specific case may be different and there are some way to go in the other direction. I will check it later.

Comment: @WeijunZhou he's not going from `BBC` to `ABC`, he's saying that if the current string is `BBC` then a possible previous string is `ABC`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou I'm not applying the inverse as a forward step, I'm entirely working backwards. If I reverse everything (all steps and make inverse-apply into a forward application) it will look more like a conventional solution.

Comment: @Nathaniel I see. Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino ^^

Comment: Which program did you use to factorize this and how long did it take?

Comment: @user202729 wolfram alpha :D

Answer (score 10):

## [feersum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157226/25180)

This is a sokoban puzzle. The starting position is:

```
          ___#
#___####_____#
#_#_#_##_#_!##
##______##_###
##__####_#_###
###__###__
```

The ending position is:

```
          ___#
#___####_____#
#_#_#_##_#_###
##____!__#_###
##__####_#_###
###__###__
```

It can be solved using the following key sequence:

> ←←→↓↓←↑←←←←←←↓↓→↑←↑↑↑←←↓→↑→↓↓→→→→→→↓→↑↑↓↓←↓←↑→↑←←←←↑←←↓→→→→→↓→→↑↑→↑↑←↓←←↓↓→↑←↑→→↑→→↓←↓←←↓↓→↑←←←←←←←↑↑←←↓→→↓→↓↓←↑←↑→↑↑←←↓→↑→↓↓←↓→↑→→→→→→↓↓←↑→↑←←←←←←→→→→→→↑↑←↓→↓←↑↑→→↑→→↓←↓←→↑↑←↓←↓↑→→↓←↑←←↓↓↓→→↑↑↓↓←←↑↑→↓↑↑→↑→→↓←↓←↓←←↑↑→→↑→↓←↓↓←←←←←↑←←↓→→→→→←←←←←↑↑←←↓→→↓↓←↑→→→→

Here is a bash program that converts the key sequence to sed commands and applies them. The sed commands contains only replacing commands using the rewrite rules defined in the cop's answer, and labelling and branching commands that doesn't modify the string. It confirms that you can get the target string using only the rewrite rules.

```bash
s="___##___####_____##_#_#_##_#_!####______##_#####__####_#_######__###__"
input=

while
    printf '\n%80s\n' "$s"|fold -w14
    read -n 1
    [ "$REPLY" = $'\e' ]
do
    read -n 2
    case "$REPLY" in
    [A)
        s="$(sed '
s:!:wLW_:
        :a
s:L:<<<<<<<<<<<<<:
s:#w<:w#:
s:_w<:w_:
s:_<:<_:
s:#<:<#:
s:#wW:wLX!:
s:_W:W_:
s:#W:W#:
s:_wW:!:
s:_X:X_:
s:#X:X#:
s:_wX:#:
        ta' <<<"$s")";;
    [B)
        s="$(sed '
s:!:_VRv:
        :a
s:R:>>>>>>>>>>>>>:
s:>v#:#v:
s:>v_:_v:
s:>_:_>:
s:>#:#>:
s:Vv#:!URv:
s:U_:_U:
s:U#:#U:
s:Uv_:#:
s:V_:_V:
s:V#:#V:
s:Vv_:!:
        ta' <<<"$s")";;
    [C)
        s="$(sed '
s:!#_:_!#:
        te
s:!_:_!:
        :e' <<<"$s")";;
    [D)
        s="$(sed '
s:_#!:#!_:
        te
s:_!:!_:
        :e' <<<"$s")";;
    esac
    input="$input${REPLY:1}"
done

echo "$input"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVJNj9owED3Hf2Evjp0q3UOlUvVQzcJKiemNQ4UEoYLKSsErkFZhtaHk0Pa30/EYsiZOV5uMkjd@8/E89s@y3p5O9UhoraWkD/3Io9d@4naVfOfR9@w5V2vBdtXTr8OIsWa7ezQsenreVYcHnq6qd18@1qsq5SKpxZ@H/eOGf2gGn1n0bEqEFR@waInk9Ou3yXfBRzxJVyblP9hm/xLziUXrsjYvYbsKs7JbFkW4heR9bTY8ZTXE0EwKDbgMJboTGPoP4JJshtBIi7RFmtAQhgQkAumiCqy0iIktoHAsgnNmAY5awMJRCM7UAqTtfyhTji3tpm/F3R2qzXvU6vn02Kqdwr3/2HL3Rwny6JAG7RACRyJHYI5R8WxK7AzZGQFkHcBM0jZHak4AKQeQivvVqlCtxPzYbc5Y37ok3nSTx0GyljHIWLfJmOm8INnU5ZpF7jaJhP7Jbzp1GPwVeCsqw5hZb/f8zIrT6WY5JlM3y5wMcXZZ9M2x6sJmF2tZRykvsmNtTOb1ajuqoG@neFiqraY8Mfn/BStPpLoWEMaHlvVJyvtG15HUO5/OYrjBVybTHlnH/CEor8Lrew@nlweR2fWUOvPPvTFm3jb90wn7hin@iMbXZd9yK954Xvn1fbD2Dw)

[Try it online (with escape code removed)!](https://tio.run/##bVFNa4NAED27v0LdFptDoYEeysYG/OgthyIkWggsNtkQIZgQ03jpf7dvZ8SmTUZZ35s3b2ZkP8tm23XNq6@1lpIO@hCjxx7ekCXOjM6eMdXaF6LdVjsjnMOxqk8bN1jW9y9PzbIOXP@u8b83@93afWzHz8I5mhKwdsdivRfOqmwMSrK399mH71a1cKKRcBxsdvfQmLUbiEZ5qp3lWiGtStCZCi9DISXbULXSIm2RJhSqkIAEkFyVo1PhkZqrnFWA3pkrlgpVsATQS4WSdv6pDFyMtL808icT4cQ3ltWL7Dwsm6npZdhu07NU8sxIK80IgEVoBBao8uYZqXOocwJQGcBJqy0gLQhAYgDJu7lscr2shN3jXzOWW0q7m3/e9MqrpaekpwcvjMyuvKYpV7js2ghhVts9rruqD18nv@vSNInjNEop4jiJ0igCA0A@oQCOUIOqhOpIZgEKXki9FQmkB87B/VBNg8jQ96cPtxq6YyEK2xatot@ePCkmZlvENB9OWxTbTbiOE3ZAasXLjf/sY0cifgA)

For up and down, `!:wLW_` or `!:_VRv` is applied for once correspondingly, and the relevant rules are applied repeatedly until the `!` appeared again. For right, one of `!#_:_!#` and `!_:_!` is applied. For left, one of `_#!:#!_` and `_!:!_` is applied.

See the output in the links for the position after each move.

Answer (score 9):

### [boboquack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157109/14109)

For a given string, take all the letters (a = 0, b = 1, c = 2), sum them up and take the modulo 3. Then none of the rewrite rules change that value. The source string has a value of 1, and the target has a value of 2. Therefore, no combination of rules will transform the source string to the target string.

Answer (score 6):

## [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157103/71546)

> Rule 1 `x:xn`
> Rule 2 `no:oon`
> Rule 3 `nr:r`
> Rule 4 `ooooooooooo:`

We use `[X,Y]` to indicate a run of Y `X`s

> Starting from `xn[o,A]r`,
>
> 1. Applying Rule 2 once we have `x[o,2]n[o,A-1]r`.
> 2. Applying Rule 2 once more we have `x[o,4]n[o,A-2]r`
> 3. Applying until the `o`s between `n` and `r` becomes 0, we have `x[o,2*A]nr`.
> 4. Applying Rule 3 once we have `x[o,2*A]r`.
> 5. Applying Rule 1 once we have `xn[o,2*A]r`.
>
> So, we have an algorithm to generate from `xn[o,A]r` to `xn[o,2*A]r`.

Starting from `xnor = xn[o,1]r`, repeating 10 times the algorithm -- except in the 10th loop we stop at Step 4, having `x[o,1024]r`.

Applying Rule 4, this clears 1023 = 11 * 93 `o`s, leaving `xor`.

Answer (score 2):

## [VortexYT](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157533/68942)

There is no way of eliminating `F`s without creating/using other characters; thus, we must use `I:F` as the last step to get to the target. No rule gives a single `I` without other unwanted characters thus you can't get to the target string.

Equivalently, if you try to map backwards from the source, you can only get from `F` to `I` before you have no more options.

Comment: Ooch, that hurts. There is another solution though...

Comment: @VortexYT oh really, there is? hm, did not know. but yeah the target can't map back more than one step which probably made this a ton easier than you intended :P

Comment: 2x easier to be exact

Answer (score 1):

## [The Empty String Photographer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/117478/the-empty-string-photographer)

The target string cannot be reached because there is no right-to-left override in the rules. That's even easier than the effort I put into formatting the original answer. Very unfunny. :p

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer how is it wrong?

Comment: still not seeing it

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer > please don't use whitespace, or symbols that are hard to distinguish from each other